# Xna - get window location?

Tags: .net, winforms, xna, window, location

I'm trying to rig an XNA WinForms system so I can have a game editor, and I need to use the mouse for it. Since the XNA Mouse input class reports mouse position based off of the window's location, I need to place the form I have in the same spot. How can i get the location of the window that my XNA game uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing it with this code:

```
        Form gameWindowForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
        ...
        myForm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(gameWindowForm.Location.X - 5,gameWindowForm.Location.Y - 5); //-5 pixels for adjustment
```

which works just dandy!

Comment: Ah, so that gives you a reference to the actual form… Good to know!

Comment: I actually got the first line from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/XNA_And_Beyond.aspx . Very helpful, though not complete, on how to get a windows forms setup to use XNA.

Comment: the -5  is going to change based on what window style is being used? So it won't work right in both classic styling, Xp styling, and vista/7 styling

Comment: @McKay: true, but since i'm using it as an internal tool, that's not a problem. If anyone plans to use it to release a tool using this technique though, then you should do some sort of switch based on window type.

Answer (score 1):

The `X` and `Y` properties of the `Game.Window.ClientBounds` struct should give you the absolute window coordinates you're looking for.

Comment: That *almost* does it, but it gives me the position of the very upper left part of the window contents, not the actual window position. See my answer for how i did it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too with my level editor. I have a picturebox in my windows Forms, so the only thing i needed to to when initializing the XNA game:

```
Mouse.WindowHandle = this.windowForm.Viewport.Handle;
```

where `Viewport` is the picturebox

now the XNA mouse position is adjusted properly automatically.